# evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2y+y^2x)}{xy} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2y+y^2x)}{xy} $$

I think that the limit doesn't exist because

$$\left|\frac{\sin(x^2y+y^2x)}{xy}\right| < \left|\frac{1}{xy}\right| \to \infty .$$ So I think the limit does not exist, but my textbook states that the limit is $0$. I don't know why.

Comment: $x^2y+yx^2=2x^2y$

Comment: $\sin X \sim X $ as $X \to 0$.

Comment: If $\lim f(x) \leq \lim g(x) = \infty$, then all you know is that $\lim f(x) \leq \infty$, so that $\lim f(x)$ could be _any_ value (including $\infty$ or $- \infty$).

Comment: @JavaMan i see thanks.

Comment: Also the argument fails generally. Easy to see that $\lim _{x \to +\infty} 1 = 1$, $\lim_{x \to +\infty} = +\infty$, even though $1 < \vert x \vert \to +\infty [x \to +\infty]$.

Comment: Expand $\sin (x^2y+y^2x)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\dfrac{\sin\left(x^{2}y+y^{2}x\right)}{xy}=\dfrac{\sin\left(x^{2}y+y^{2}x\right)}{x^{2}y+y^{2}x}\dfrac{x^{2}y+y^{2}x}{xy}=\dfrac{\sin\left(x^{2}y+y^{2}x\right)}{x^{2}y+y^{2}x}\left(x+y\right)$$